# Migrate to Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

I've been trying for days but I can not solve my problem.
I state that I started to create my own web page on Mysql and it works perfectly. I had to migrate to Postgres and the problems started here.

For example there:

I have this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on
>   string in C:\xampp\input.php:39 Stack trace: #0
>   {main}

```
$checkdata = "SELECT count(*) as prenotato
  FROM Prenotazione
 WHERE data='$data'
   AND NOT ('$newTimeEnd' < orario_inizio OR orario_fine < '$orario_inizio')";

$prenotato = $conn_string->query($checkdata)->pg_fetch_row()[0];
```

this is the config.php file that i used:

```
<?php

$conn_string = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=123456789";
$dbconn = pg_connect($conn_string);

?>
```

EDIT.

I follow your suggests:

config.php

```
<?php 
$dbname = "postgres";
$host = "localhost";
$username = "postgres";
$dbh = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host", $username, 123456789 ); 
?>
```

For example i have another problem about a similar error:

> Warning: pg_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\select.php on line 5
>
> Warning: pg_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\select.php on line 18

```
<?php  
 require ('config.php');
 $output = '';  
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM Prenotazione where data = CURRENT_DATE()"; 
 $result = pg_query($dbh, $sql);  
 $output .= '  
      <div class="table-responsive">  
           <table class="table table-bordered">  
                <tr>  

                     <th width="10%">Nominativo</th>  
                     <th width="20%">Data</th> 
                     <th width="5%">Orario Inizio</th>
                     <th width="5%">Orario Fine</th>
                     <th width="5%">Email</th>
                     <th width="50%">Oggetto</th>
                </tr>';  
 $rows = pg_num_rows($result);
 if($rows > 0)  
 {
```

How can i solve this problem?? 
Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$conn_string` is a string, not an object, so you can't call any methods on it! Even the variable name tells you so!

Are you  sure you didn't mean to create a new PDO connection using that string?

Your string should be like this example:

```
$postgresDsn = 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=testdb;user=someone;password=mypass'

$db = new PDO($postgresDsn, $user, $password);
```

Check the docs for PDO here:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Also, specific instructions for postgres:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.connection.php

> UPDATE

I just noticed, you aren't using `$dbconn`. Try changing:

```
$prenotato = $conn_string->query($checkdata)->pg_fetch_row()[0];
```

to

```
$prenotato = $dbconn->query($checkdata)->pg_fetch_row()[0];
```

Regardless, check PDO out, it's more secure, and easier to work with.

Comment: And i don't need to do a connection? Like i have done?

Comment: This is the better way of creating a connection, using PDO. Give it a try!

Comment: @delboy1987uk ok man, thank you. Can you help me another time?? I edit my first post!

Answer (score 0):

As your first problem is already answered and you switched to PDO I'll answer your follow-up question.

Since you are now using PDO you cant use the `pg_*` methods. You need to use the PDO methods now. See the documentation for [PDO::query](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.query.php) for more information about how to use them.

This should work with your query:

```
$rows = $dbh->query($sql);
```